# Regular Expression match but not include

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to use regular expression to only select the bolded (minus the *'s) based on the below string (carriage returns are in the string).  Every string that I want to select it out of begins with ISA.  I've been trying to work with this, `(?<=ISA\\*)(\w*)`, but whenever I start adding additional characters to exclude in the `(?<...)` part, I no longer find any matches.

ISA*00*         *00*          *ZZ*SOME STRING  *ZZ*99999999  ***130605*** 2239*|*00501*000000001*0*P*>

REF*TJ*12345677*

REF*PQ*23432211

LX*1

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use Regex for this?

Comment: What defines the "bit you care about"? There are many asterisks, so what is special about your number - is it "space-asterisk-sequence of digits-asterisk-space"?

Comment: @AllenG I don't have to use regex but the characters leading up to the bolded part can be dynamic...and there could be multiple within a string, this is a small snippet

Comment: @Floris the asterisk number will be the same (so between the 9th and 10th), but the text in between each asterisk is not set

Comment: I know X12, I feel your pain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following should work:

```
^ISA(?:[^*]*[*][^*]*){8}\*(\d+)\*
```

See http://regex101.com/r/lU8sC8/1

The way it works:

```
^ISA          — start of string has "ISA"
(?:           — non-capturing group
[^*]*[*][^*]* — zero or more non-asterisks, followed by asterisk, followed by non-asterisk
{8}           — eight of these
\*            — one more asterisk
(\d+)         — capture one or more digits
\*            — followed by another asterisk
```

Comment: And yours gets my vote for the documentation and using something other than Rubular. :-) I'm lazy on both counts. ;-)

Comment: @PeterAlfvin - thanks. I only recently discovered regex101.com - but I much prefer it. They have a wonderful way of describing your expression in words, and using color to show "what goes where". Really terrific tool.

Answer (score 2):

If it's numbers between the 9th and 10th asterisk, then you can use:

```
ISA(?:[^*]*\*){9}(\d+)\*
```

as shown in this [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/wEpIOE2XEs)

Comment: Very similar to my solution, but yours is more compact, and gets my vote. I'll leave mine up for now because I think the explanation of the expression adds something to the discussion.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use Regex to parse X12 EDI documents.  A good place to start would be [here](http://timrayburn.net/blog/parsing-an-x12-edi-by-hand/)

Looking at that link, you'll find that your field delimiter is ALWAYS at position 104 of the ISA line, your subdelimiter is always at position 105 of the ISA line, and your record delimiter is always at 106.  (If they're not there, you don't have valid X12).

Using that, I'd do something like this (if you're looking specifically for field 7 of the ISA record):

```
var fieldDelimiter = line[103]; //where 'line' = your ISA Line, and remember 0 based index
var fieldSubDelim = line[104];
var recordDelimiter = line[105];

var fields = line.Split(fieldDelimiter);
var yourField = fields[7];
```

This also allows you to sort through your other records in a similar fashion, should you need to do so.